# Increase the size of a 2D-Array inside a function with realloc and calloc

Tags: c, function, multidimensional-array, segmentation-fault, dynamic-memory-allocation

I want to store multiple strings (aka arrays of chars) in an array. Therefore, I want to use a 2D-Array. Since I do not know the exact sizes (neither the length of the individual strings nor the number of strings), I need to increase the size dynamically.

For a better structure, I want to this inside a separate function. However, if I access my Array after resizing it, apparently the size has not changed, and I get a segmentation fault.

I am fairy new to C (coming from a C++ background)

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

//I want to increase my array from [1][5] to [2][5]
void increase(char*** data)
{
    *data = realloc(*data, 2 * sizeof (char*));
    *data[1] = calloc(5, sizeof(char));
}

int main(void)
{
    char** data  = calloc(1, sizeof(char*));
    data[0] = calloc(5, sizeof(char));

    increase(&data);

    data[1][3] = 'a'; //<-- When I access the array I get an segmentation fault

    free(data);
  
  return 0;
}
```

Is my approach with a `char***` correct? I could implement it in a test environment directly in the main function and it worked. But, as soon as encapsulated it inside a function, I got a seg. fault.

I assume it has something to do with the way I pass the array to the function, but I cannot figure out what the cause of this is and how to solve it. Has anyone some ideas or maybe a solution?

Comment: @AdrianMole You were right. Just fixed the example.

Comment: Note that `*data[1]` is parsed as `*(data[1])`, not as `(*data)[1]`. And `data[1]` does not exist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error (which is subtly catastrophic) is in how you are attempting to allocate the second element of your passed pointer array, and is related to [operator precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence). Note that the array subscript operator, `[]` has *higher* precedence than the indirection operator, `*`.

Thus, your line:

```c
*data[1] = calloc(5, sizeof(char));
```

actually has the effect of:

```c
*(data[1]) = calloc(5, sizeof(char));
```

This, as you can hopefully see, is really *not* what you want to do.

Instead, you need:

```c
(*data)[1] = calloc(5, sizeof(char));
```

Another problem (though not an error, *per se*) is that you aren't doing any error checks on your allocations; this is especially important when using `realloc` because, as your code stands, you will lose the 'original' pointer if that call fails. It is better to store the return value from `realloc` in a temporary, then overwrite the original only if that temporary is not `NULL`.

Here's a possible re-working of your code (you could/should add more error checks on the `calloc` calls, though):

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int increase(char*** data)
{
    char** temp = realloc(*data, 2 * sizeof(char*));
    if (temp != NULL) {
        *data = temp;   // Only overwrite the original if we succeed!
        (*data)[1] = calloc(5, sizeof(char));
        return 1;
    }
    else {
        printf("Allocation error!"); // But we still have our original "data" pointer
        return 0;
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    char** data = calloc(1, sizeof(char*));
    data[0] = calloc(5, sizeof(char));
    if (increase(&data)) {
        data[1][3] = 'a';
        printf("%c\n", data[1][3]); // Just to do some testing!
        free(data[1]); // Free the second (added) block
    }
    free(data[0]) // Free the first (original) block
    free(data); // "data" will be valid whether or not our call to "increase" works
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: the problem is that there are no 2D arrays in your code. The question is about 2D arrays. arrays of pointers are not 2D arrays

Comment: `(*data)[1] = calloc(5, sizeof(char));` - no it is wrong `(*data)[1]` is a pointer to single element char array - which in the context of the question makes no sense at all

Comment: @0___________ `(*data)[1]` is a `char*` pointer. That is being given the returned value of `calloc(5, sizeof(char))`.

Comment: @0___________ Not sure what you actually meant, but `(*data)[1]` is actually a single element of an array of pointers (equivalent to `temp[1]`, in my code); I'm really confused about how you get *is a pointer to single element char array*.

Comment: @0___________ Unless, of course, *you* are getting confused: `char (*data)[1];` **declares** a pointer to a single-element char array ... but *nowhere* in my code is there such a declaration.

Answer (score 0):

1. You do not have any 2D arrays in your code only array of pointer. Your question is about 2D arrays..

Trivial code (the number of columns does not change)

```
void *alloc2D(const size_t rows, const size_t cols, char (*arr)[cols])
{
    arr = realloc(arr, rows * sizeof(*arr));
    return arr;
}
```

Less trivial code - both are changing.

```
void *alloc2D(const size_t rows, const size_t cols, const size_t oldrows, const size_t oldcols, char (*arr)[oldcols])
{
    char (*newarr)[cols] = malloc(rows * sizeof(*newarr));

    if(arr && newarr)
    {
        for(size_t r = 0; r < rows && r < oldrows; r++)
        {
            memcpy(newarr[r], arr[r], sizeof(*arr) > sizeof(*newarr) ? sizeof(*newarr) : sizeof(*arr));p
        }
    }   
    if(newarr) free(arr);
    return newarr;
}
```

And some usage:

```
void *increase(const size_t oldrows, const size_t oldcols, char (*arr)[oldcols])
{
    return alloc2D(oldrows+1, oldcols, arr);
}

int main(void)
{
    size_t rows;
    size_t cols;

    if(scanf("%zu", &rows) != 1) { /* error handling*/}
    if(scanf("%zu", &cols) != 1) { /* error handling*/}

    char (*arr)[cols] = alloc2D(rows, cols, NULL);
    char (*narr)[cols];

    narr = increase(rows, cols, arr);
    if(narr) arr = narr;

    free(narr);
  
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Where do you allocate new memory for your columns?

Comment: @David9472 read the code - everything is there